# C# WebBrowser and multithreading

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I have a class whose main function is:

```
public void SendSMS(SendInfo info, WebBrowser browser)
{
    browser.Width = 300;
    browser.Height = 300;
    browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    browser.DocumentCompleted += Browser_Navigated;
    this.number = info.number;
    this.message = info.template;
    if (info.proxy != null) { WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = info.proxy; }
    debugCode = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["tabControl1"].Controls["tabPage1"].Controls["DebugCode"] as TextBox;
    debugImage = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["tabControl1"].Controls["tabPage1"].Controls["pictureBox1"] as PictureBox;
    MessageBox.Show("I'am start send, template: " + info.template);
    browser.Navigate("My secret url :)");
}
```

After browser navigated,invoke second main function:

```
private void SendPostRequest(string number, string message, string captcha_key, string captcha_result)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Number: " + number + " Message: " + message + " key: " + captcha_key +" result: " + captcha_result);
    string postData = "Body=" + message + "&Captcha=" + captcha_result + "&CheckboxTransliterate=false&Phone=" + number.Substring(3, number.Length - 3) + "&PhoneCode=" + number.Substring(0, 3) + "&WidgetId=" + captcha_key + "&_captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&clearJson=true";
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    HttpWebRequest sendRequest = WebRequest.Create("My secret url :") as HttpWebRequest;
    sendRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    sendRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36";
    sendRequest.Method = "POST";
    sendRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    sendRequest.Referer = "My secret url :";
    sendRequest.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
    sendRequest.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    sendRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, *";
    sendRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookies);
    sendRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
    sendRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    sendRequest.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sendRequest.RequestUri);
    using (Stream dataStream = sendRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);}
    onSendCompleted(sendRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
}

private void onSendCompleted(Stream SendResponsetStream)
{
    string status = new StreamReader(SendResponsetStream).ReadToEnd();
    SendResponsetStream.Close();
    ArgumentsClass args = new ArgumentsClass();
    args.ResponseMessage = status;
    args.ResponseNumber = number;
    OnSmsSendend(this, args);
}
```

How can I run it's void(Send SMS with its subfunctions) in other threads?
I need these functions(Send SMS with its subfunctions) to be run in parallel.
Thanks!

P.S. Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you want to run `SendSMS` and `SendPostRequest` parallelly?

Comment: No, SendSMS invoke SendPostRequest herself, i need run only SendSMS parallelly in programm main class.

Comment: You mean asynchronously? What you want to run in parallel with `SendSMS`? There has to be another function which runs in parallel to it.

Comment: Yes, I mean asynchronously and many - many concurrently running SendSMS functions

Comment: Will the parameters in `SendSMS` be different for every concurrent calls or it will be same for all?

Comment: The parameters will be different for everyone, they should be called from an array

Answer (score 0):

Since your `SendSMS` does not necessarily need to return anything and the parameters would come from a collection (an array or something similar), you can do something like this-

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objjectInstance.SendSMS(input[info], input[browser]))); //objectInstance is class object instance
}
```

Here `inputs` is a collection of the input parameters of type- `SendInfo` and `WebBrowser`. You have to create the input parameter collection accordingly as per need.

Comment: Main problem - it's using browser in another thread. In this code, i had "ThreadStateException", because WebBrowser can work in only STA thread.

Comment: If I create a WebBrowser in the main thread, and then I pass it to the SendSMS function, an InvalidOperationException error occurs.
If I create a WebBrowser in the SendSMS function itself, then a ThreadStateException error occurs

Comment: Code `foreach (var SendInfo in BeelineSendInfos)
            {
                Thread th = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    beeline.SendSMS(SendInfo, new WebBrowser());
                });
                th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                th.Start();
            }` don't work absolutely

Comment: You have to make sure that the code inside SendSMS is completely Thread safe. You might implement locks within the required code but it will reduce the performance.